# How did the Prophet ﷺ bring the Quranic Revelation into public?

Tags: quran, hadith, revelation

Is there anything stated in Hadith literature how the Surahs were transferred to public?
In particular the longer ones: Were they first written down accoding to the words of the Prophet ﷺ or did he repeat them until others learned them?

I know that the Prophet ﷺ used to recite with his scolars behind him. I can imagine that the early surah were memorised in this way as (even though it takes me quite long to learn a short surah, but I am very bad at memorising).
However, he even used to recite in silence (e.g. [Muslim 4:44](https://sunnah.com/muslim:396a)), so it was possibly not meant to teach during prayer.
I wonder in particular whether the longer, less poetic surahs may have been written down in an early stage.

Comment: The qur'an generally was revealed piece wise. I'd say your inquiry has answers on the site maybe the tag [tag:revelation] could already display some.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I found a lot of interesting answers but not on the question.

Comment: Well duplicate on stackexchange is if the question has an answer somewhere.